# Kmeans code for 3 dimensions with my own constraint in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to cluster a group of buildings based on their distance and the population in that building. I have the coordinates for each building. I tried to do it but I am having difficulty in coding the same.

I can cluster it based on distance but don't know how to cluster it based on both distance and population. Also I have a constraint that the population in one cluster should not be more than 100 people in a cluster

The data is like a matrix. An X by 3 matrix. The first column is the latitude as a decimal. The second column is longitude as a decimal and the third column is the population at that latitude,longitude as a number. The constraint is that after clustering based on the first two columns, the sum of the numbers in the third column of the respective points present in a cluster should not be more that 100. I hope this clears up about the constraint

Comment: I don't get the constraint. Regarding population + coordinates, you will need to scale your problem according to your needs. There is no way that `kmeans` (or any other algorithm) inherently knows the difference between coordinates and population -- in particular, as it will only take matrix as input

Comment: The data is like a matrix. An X by 3 matrix. The first column is the latitude as a decimal. The second column is longitude as a decimal and the third column is the population at that latitude,longitude as a number. The constraint is that after clustering based on the first two columns, the sum of the numbers in the third column of the respective points present in a cluster should not be more that 100. I hope this clears up about the constraint.

Comment: There is no way in using constraints in `kmeans` (as Matlab native). You will have to implement it yourself

Comment: So how can you do it?